# convert and Insert date format in nodejs into Oracle timestamp

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

```js
let date = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000000000 A");
```

// when i tried to insert date in table it is null

// TImestamp format in OracleDB is 14-03-22 3:53:08.901008000 PM

INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(join_date) ( '14-03-22 3:53:08.901008000 PM')

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a complete example including your `INSERT` code in NodeJS.

Comment: Notice that moment library is entered in maintenance mode, see project status: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: How can get date format like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FF3 AM/PM because in oracle it supports this kind of timestamp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, make sure that you read [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before asking any question.

Answer (score 1):

> How can get date format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FF3 AM/PM` because in oracle it supports this kind of timestamp

In Oracle, a `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data type that consists of 7 - 13 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second and between zero and six bytes for fractional seconds). It **ALWAYS** contains those components and it is **NEVER** stored in a particular format.

The client application you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, NodeJS, Java, etc.) may chose to **DISPLAY** the binary value with a default format but this is a function of the client application and **NOT** a function of the database. (Some client applications may use the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter from the database as their default format model but the implicit conversion from binary-to-string for display purposes is still something that the client application does, not the database, and not all clients use the database session variables for their defaults.)

You should either:

1. Use a timestamp literal:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO STUDENT (join_date) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2022-03-14 15:53:08.901008000');
   ```
2. Explicitly convert your formatted string to a timestamp binary data type using the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function with a format model:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO STUDENT (join_date)
   VALUES (
     TO_TIMESTAMP('14-03-22 3:53:08.901008000 PM', 'DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF9 AM')
   )
   ```